# Parsing Email with Ruby: unexpected token ATOM (expected SPACE) (Net::IMAP::ResponseParseError)

Tags: ruby, email

I am getting started parsing email with Ruby. I'm trying to read from my GMail account:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mail'

Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :imap, :address    => "imap.gmail.com",
                          :port       => 995,
                          :user_name  => 'example@gmail.com',
                          :password   => 'password',
                          :enable_ssl => true
end

emails = Mail.all

emails.each do |email|
    puts email.inspect
end
```

...but I'm getting this error:

```
/Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:3277:in `parse_error': unexpected token ATOM (expected SPACE) (Net::IMAP::ResponseParseError)
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:3129:in `match'
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:2100:in `continue_req'
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:2087:in `response'
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:2015:in `parse'
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1166:in `get_response'
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1051:in `initialize'
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/network/retriever_methods/imap.rb:143:in `new'
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/network/retriever_methods/imap.rb:143:in `start'
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/network/retriever_methods/imap.rb:65:in `find'
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/network/retriever_methods/base.rb:41:in `all'
    from /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/mail.rb:171:in `all'
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's IMAP parser has had bugs. Your error output shows that the problem isn't likely to be in your code, it's likely to be the Ruby IMAP parser code that you can't easily change without patching Ruby.

If you're just interested in Gmail, and want to try a easier solution, try the Gmail gem:

https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail

If you're interested in knowing the details of what's happening and possily how to patch Ruby:

http://claudiofloreani.blogspot.com/2012/01/monkeypatching-ruby-imap-class-to-build.html

Comment: I was hoping to be able to work with multiple providers, but that does look like a nice gem. =]

Answer (score 1):

This error message is typical if you try to do IMAP on a POP3 mail server.

Google Mail's IMAP port is 993. The port you tried is for POP3.